# how can i get the 10 largest files using ftw

Tags: c

I am trying to get the 10 largest files in a directory.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ftw.h> 
#include <string.h>

typedef struct File{
    char path[1000];
    long size;
}File;

File array_file[10];
int compt = 0;
int i = 0;

int fn(const char *fpath, const struct stat *sb, int typeflag){
    switch (typeflag)
    {
    case FTW_F:
        if(compt < 10){
            strcpy(array_file[compt].path, fpath);
            array_file[compt].size = sb->st_size;
            compt += 1;
            }
        for(i; i < 10; i++){
            if(sb->st_size > array_file[i].size){
                printf("i am here \n");
                strcpy(array_file[i].path, fpath);
                array_file[i].size = sb->st_size;
            }
        }
        break;
    case FTW_D:
        break;
    case FTW_DNR:
        return -1;
    case FTW_NS:
        return -1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

this is my main :

```c
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    if(argc > 1){
        ftw(argv[1], fn, 20);
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        printf("%s\n", array_file[i].path);
        printf("%ld\n", array_file[i].size);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

when i try to check the file size and replace it in my structure i get the same file in the structure 10 times.

i am new to C coding so mistakes can be made O.o, thank you for your help !

Comment: I assume this is a C programming exercise, but if it's a practical problem, I wouldn't bother writing a C program, I'd just invoke `ls -lS | head`.

Comment: Yes it is i would’ve done the same by executing a shell command but i am forced to do this @SteveSummit

Comment: Usually, it's better to use [`nftw()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/nftw.html) than [`ftw()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/ftw.html).  However, that shouldn't stop the `ftw()` version from working.

Comment: In `fn()`, the `case FTW_F:` should not execute the `for` loop if the `if` statement is executed.  You also need to terminate the `for` loop once you've found one file smaller than the current file.